# CodeIgniter: Constants.php constant pulled from DB

Tags: codeigniter, routes

My controller `squad` manages all the functionality of an internal group within the larger community of the CMS.  I would like to offer admin the ability to change the verb that refers to this group.  Examples of such could be: `team`, `wing`, `platoon`, or even `dogfood` if it satisfies them.

The problem I am encountering is needing to pull the routing from a database string so `site.com/squad` becomes the value the administrator sets.  However. one cannot do this without a) hacking the core or b) extending the CI_Router.

I have started the extension, but only got this far:

```
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {
    function MY_Router()
    {
        $this->config =& get_config();
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

All I would like to accomplish is:

```
define('UNIT', $this->get_setting('squad-term'));
$route[UNIT] = "squad";
```

Does anybody have an approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend of mine found [this article](http://osvaldas.info/blog/smart-database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter) and the solution works perfectly.  Granted it takes another db request, but that's the price to pay.

`config/routes.php`

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->where('setting_slug', 'squad-term')->get( '_settings' );
$result = $query->result();
$term = lcfirst($result[0]->setting_value);

$route[$term] = "squad";
$route[$term . 's'] = "squads";
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do this is to prepend a string (ex: squad_) to the segment which you can then match with a regex in routes.php

```
site.com/squad_team
site.com/squad_squad
site.com/squad_dogfood
```

Or a bit cleaner, add another 'level' which you can then match in routes.php via `$route['s/(:any)']`

```
site.com/s/team
site.com/s/squad
site.com/s/food
```

Having said that, I'm not sure why you

> need to rewrite the squad controller's name

?

Comment: Doing this still requires the route search to be dynamic.  Allow me to be more clear.  The functionality for group actions (manage users, community walls, messages, news, etc) is handled by the controller `squad`.  Since not every installing admin wants to call the divisions of his community 'squads', i set up a method to change the verb, ie to `team`.  It is quite silly to have a controller that handles the management of your 'teams' to be called 'squad', don't you think?  Therefore, i want to conditionally route the controller based on the verb assigned in the database.